# Convert JSON data into javascript object with key and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have below json parse data and i am trying to convert it to javascript object

```
usrPrefs
    [Object { name="mystocks", value="500400,532500,500180,500312,500325"},
     Object { name="mystocksname", value="Tata Power,Maruti Suzuki...NGC,Reliance Industries"},
     Object { name="refresh_secs", value="600"}]
```

i am trying to convert this to something like below

```
myparam = {
  mystocks:500400,532500,500180,500312,500325,
  mystocksname:Tata Power,Maruti Suzuki...NGC,Reliance Industries
....
}
```

how i can do that in javascript something like using loop or any build in function, i started learning javascript and i am stuck here...

thank you in advance.

Regards,
Mona

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: And var myArray = []; myArray = JSON.parse(usrPrefs); doesn't work?

Comment: As all answers are correct. i have voted all. But accepted which one suits my need. Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `reduce` function in order to achieve that:

```
var myparam = usrPrefs.reduce(function(a, b){
  a[b.name] = b.value;
  return a;
}, {});
```

Comment: This will return an array of objects each with a single key and value, which is not what is wanted.

Comment: @Stuart True! I'm gonna fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var myparam = {};

for (var i = 0; i < usrPrefs.length; i++) {
    myparam[usrPrefs[i].name] = usrPrefs[i].value;
}
```

Comment: Why are you skipping the last element of the array? You need to change `i < usrPrefs.length - 1` to `i < usrPrefs.length`

Comment: My bad, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You might choose to use array instead of string, its more convenient for you to use

```
function toMap(usrPrefs){ 
     var result = {};
     for(var i = 0 ; i < usrPrefs.length ; i++){
         var obj = usrPrefs[i];
         var array =  obj.value.split(',').trim();
         result[obj.name] = array;
      }
      return result;
 };
```